# Amount of grease needed on a typical wheel bearing.

Tags: bearing, grease

Replacing front wheel bearings on a RWD truck.  Inner and Outer.   Will 14oz tube of grease be plenty?   Is there a rough estimate per bearing or does it depend on the type?

Answer (score 2):

You lube the bearings until all the old grease is out. Can't really tell if 14oz is enough, but if using one of those fancy repackers, it might be. If replacing all together, just make sure there is enough grease in them. Some come pre-greased, but I would repack anyways. Can never really tell how long they been sitting in a parts room.